# How do I change a parameter in a URL upon submitting in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, url

I want the following URL to be manipulated and opened in a new tab once I pass the value of email ID and click submit. The searchText in `myUrl` is the `param` for email ID:

HTML:

```
<textarea name="email" id="email" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button id="myButton">submit</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
const myUrl = new URL('something.com?searchText=weijsdo@hotmail.com&site=something&mobileVersion=&locale=&forceAaaApplication=');
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

HTML:

```
<button id="myButton" onclick="sbButtonClick()">submit</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
const textarea = document.getElementById("email");
let myUrl = null;

function sbButtonClick() {
    myUrl = new URL(`something.com?searchText=${textarea.value}&site=something&mobileVersion=&locale=&forceAaaApplication=`);

    // do something with myUrl
}
```

### Edit

to get multiple email addresses one of the easiest ways is this way:

```js
const textarea = document.getElementById("email");

function sbButtonClick() {
    // split the text by line breaks so each address should be in a separate line
    const emailArray = textarea.value.split("\n");

    // here you open tab for each email address
    for (let address of emailArray) {
        window.open(`something.com?searchText=${address}&site=something&mobileVersion=&locale=&forceAaaApplication=`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful :) Can you also show me how I can input multiple emails at once and on submit it will open multiple tabs?

Comment: here I edited the post for what you asked. please let me know if you need further information :)